# How to get Angularjs scope variable after reloadWithDebugInfo?

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I have an angularjs web page and want to get the specified element's scope. But after executing the reloadWithDebugInfo function, the result is null;

```
    private Page _page;
    private Browser _browser;

    private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await initAsync();
            await test2Async();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private async Task initAsync()
    {
        _browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false,
            ExecutablePath = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
            Timeout = 60000
        });
    }

    private async Task test2Async()
    {
        try
        {
            _page = await _browser.NewPageAsync();

            await _page.GoToAsync("https://SOME Angular JS WebPage");

            await _page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(@"() => angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()");

            var scopeContent = await _page.EvaluateFunctionAsync("() => angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('left-column-v3')).scope() ");

            // scopeContent is null. why? (the above javascript code runs successfully in the chrome dev console.)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

These statements works well in chrome dev tools.
I expect the json content of the scope, but that is null;

Update:
sorry, I forgot something after Scope().
I want a variable in the scope, not scope itself:

```
        var scopeContent = await _page.EvaluateFunctionAsync("() => angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('left-column-v3')).scope().SomeVariable ");
```

Comment: Is the scope serializable?

Comment: I don't know about that. I just want to fetch some data from the scope.

Comment: @hardkoded
I think the problem is angular.reloadWithDebugInfo() and reloading the page and destroying the previous context; But I don't know how can solve that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of the scope function is not serializable.
You would need to build a serializable object inside the `EvaluateFunctionAsync` and return that.

[image: Javascript error]

Comment: yeah you right. I just updated my question; I forgot the variable after scope().